# How to convert curl command to postman(PayPal disputes API)

Tags: postman

I encountered a problem while developing [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/#disputes-actions_provide-evidence)

This curl command is something I have n’t encountered before and it has n’t been resolved for a long time
Please help me
How to convert to postman format, my import using postman cannot be recognized correctly

code:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-27803/provide-evidence \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-F 'input={
  "evidences": [
{
  "evidence_type": "PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT",
  "evidence_info": {
  "tracking_info": [
    {
    "carrier_name": "FEDEX",
    "tracking_number": "122533485"
    }
  ]
  },
  "notes": "Test"
}
  ]
};type=application/json' \
-F 'file1=@NewDoc.pdf'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

我自己解决了

看图片

目前只能使用curl成功    postman   python requests   php  都没有成功

主要还是后面这个@符号

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTCoP.png)